# Kusto KQL equivalent to string_agg in mysql

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

Is there a way to concatenate a column in Kusto KQL?

For example, for some `world` dataset with a column `name` in MySQL (v8):

```sql
select group_agg(name) from world;
```

would result in:

```
| string_agg                                    |
|-----------------------------------------------|
| Afghanistan,Azerbaijan,Bahrain,Bangladesh,... |
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [make_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/makeset-aggfunction) to create dynamic array of the unique values and then you can use [strcat_array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/strcat-arrayfunction) to get a string value of the list. For example:

```
StormEvents
| take 10
// get array of the distinct values
| summarize make_set(State) 
// get a string value of the array
| extend states = strcat_array(set_State, ", ")
```

Results:
[image]

Comment: Just to add that there is also a `make_list` if removal of duplicates is not required (probably not useful for the case in this question but I came across this answer whilst working on a case where I did want to extract the duplicates so might help future visitors)

Comment: `make_list` seems to preserve order as well, which was helpful for me.